# How do you make a sword attack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you guys make a sword attack? I asking this question because I don't know how to make a sword attack and the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjkSFoLxesw&t) that I am watching only shows a projectile attack. I want to learn how to make a sword attack for a game that I am creating.
Here is the code that I am showing

```
    void AttackPlayer()
{
    //Make sure that the enemy doesn't move
    agent.SetDestination(transform.position);

    transform.LookAt(player);
    if (!alreadyAttacked)
    {
        //Attack Code Is underneath
        Rigidbody rb = Instantiate(projectile, transform.positino, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 32f, ForceMode.Impulse);
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 8f, ForceMode.Impulse);

        //Attack Code Is Above. I want a sword attack instead of a projectile
        alreadyAttacked = true;
        Invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttacks);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 3D object for your sword, along with an animation, you can add collider to it, and enable it for the duration of the swing animation.

The above will be very accurate, but that may not be the behavior you actually want. If you want something a bit more "easy" for the player to use, you could add a separate object with a sphere collider in front of the player. And similarly, you would enable it for the duration of the animation, or maybe even a split second.

Probably an even better approach would be to use [SphereCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) in your code to do a "moment in time" check for the area in front of the player. Sample code from the docs, modified a little:

```
void Attack()
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    // _hitCenterGameObject would be a GameObject you would create under your character GameObject. Position it wherever you want the hit to be centered
    // This makes it really easy to see and understand where your attack will be in relation to you character
    var spherePosition = _hitCenterGameObject.position;
    
    // How big is the sphere going to be
    var radius = 1f;

    float distanceToObstacle = 0;

    // Cast a sphere to see if it we hit anything.
    if (Physics.SphereCast(spherePosition, radius, transform.forward, out hit, 10))
    {
        // You got a hit, probably want to figure out what it is, and whether or not to apply damage.
        distanceToObstacle = hit.distance;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You may want to use `SphereCastAll` since it will return all objects hit by the raycast. Or maybe you would vary that based on the weapon or attack type. Maybe a swing can hit multiple targets while a stab can only hit one? Just a thought.